# How to Default Route in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, default

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET Core 6, and now following a tutorial using ASP.NET Core 2. After adding the controller phase they delete this line from the startup file

```
app.run(async (context) = await context.response.writeasync("hello world"))
```

and add

```
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

so they can see the views.

As you know there is no startup file in ASP.NET Core 6, and I don't know what to do at this point.

I searched the internet a lot and have nothing.

I try to adjust the code in the program file like that

```
app.MapGet("/", () => app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute);
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asp.net core6 we define the default route like this:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You can read [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to  know more.

Comment: thanx, and you have to add this service builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();